# Java phonebook with stored file

Tags: java, file, class

I wrote a program to ask user to input names, numbers, and any notes associated. I then am trying to allow the user to search any name and have that persons info displayed. I also want to be able to store and read a file from the phone book. I am having trouble with the store/read as well as recognizing a separate class that was created. I'm guessing I just have syntax errors because I am still new to programming. Thanks for any help!

```
public class Entry {
    public String name, num, notes;
    name = a;
    num = b;
    notes = c;
}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Phonebook {

    static int amount;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static file f ("FileName");

    public static Entry[] pb = new Entry[200];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ask;
        char letter;

        amount = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a command");
            ask = input.nextLine();
            letter = Character.toLowerCase(ask.charAt(0));

            switch (letter) {
            case 'e': System.out.println(add()); break;
            case 'f': System.out.println(find()); break;
            case 'l': System.out.println(list()); break;
            case 'h': System.out.println(help()); break;
            case 'q': System.out.println("Quit"); break;
            default: System.out.println("Not a valid command"); break;
            }
        } while (letter != 'q');

    }
    public static void help() {
        System.out.println("Use e for enter");
        System.out.println("Use f for find");
        System.out.println("Use l for list");
        System.out.println("Use h to see this menu again");
    }
    public static void add() {
        String a, b, c;

        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        a = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        b = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter any notes: ");
        c = input.nextLine();
    }
    public static void list() {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            System.out.println(pb[i].name + pb[i].num + pb[i].notes);
    }
    public static void find () {
        String f;
        boolean found;
        found = false;

        System.out.println("Who?");
        f = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++); {
            if (f.equals((pb[i].name))) {
                System.out.println(pb[i].name + pb[i].num + pb[i].notes);
                found = true;
            } if (!found)
                System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
    public static void WritePhoneBook (String f) throws Exception {
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            p.println(pb[i].name + pb[i].num + pb[i].notes);
            p.close();
            System.out.println("Phonebook stored.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to show the errors I received but they are:

- file cannot be resolved to type
- i cannot be resolved
- PrintStream cannot be resolved,
- Syntax error at FileName,
- method println(boolean) in type PrintStream is not applicable.

Comment: If you're seeing compilation errors and need help, you should ***post*** those compilation errors here so that we can read them, don't you think?

Comment: I see `static file f ("FileName");`. `File` needs to be capital unless you defined your own file class and it is lowercase. You may also be missing some imports.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code does not even compile, let me look at the compilation errors only (and not the logic):

- `static file f ("FileName");`

  1. It is `File` (uppercase F). In java, by convention, all classes start with a uppercase letter.
  2. the statement is not correctly constructed. It is supposed to be

`static File f = "FileName";`

or something like this. Note that you need to `import java.io.File` as well.

- `System.out.println(add());`
  ...

the methods add, find... return void. Meaning, they return nothing. System.out.println() does not operate on nothing.

- `PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);`

you have not imported `java.io.PrintStream`.

- `i` cannot be resolved to a variable

This is because of the `;` at the end of the `for`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {  //note: no ; after the )
        if (f.equals((pb[i].name))) {
```

In `Entry.java`

- the class lacks a method. Assignments like `name = a;` are not valid outside a method, Also `a`, `b` and `c` are not defined.

It looks like you are very new to Java. You may want to use a IDE like eclipse so that you get a better picture of errors and recommended fixes and you can fix them faster. However, you will learn more and learn better if you use `javac` from the command line (which is what I think you are doing).  Of course you need to do a lot of reading and learning.

***PS:*** Such questions will most likely be downvoted to oblivion because it shows a lack of effort from the OP's part to find solutions. I happened to have a few minutes today, but no one has the time to look into this level of detail when there *seems* to be no effort from OP.

<sup>OP = Original Poster = the person that asked the question</sup>